# convert string to name of existing variable to use var value in batch

Tags: string, variables, batch-file

I am generating strings with the names of existing variables. I want to use the strings to create a variable set to the VALUE of the existing variable, but I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Put another way if this helps:
A calling routine sends strings "abc" "cde" etc... Each string is the first several characters of a path variable I've already set. I then append "path" to the passed string to create the full name of the existing variable (e.g., %abcpath%) Now I want to get the value of %abcpath% and put it into a variable I can use it in the current routine.

Thanks for any help.

Here is part of the code I have:

```
SET abcPath=c:\path_to_abc_dir
SET cdePath=c:\path_to_cde_dir

call :names abc cde ...

:names
 For %%G in (%*) do (
    set name=%%G
    :: Append "path" to name from calling routine
    set namepath=!name!path
    echo "!namepath!"       
    :: 1st time through namepath is "abcPath"
    :: How to now set a var to the VALUE of %abcPath% set above?

    ::these don't work:
    set dirpath=%%namepath%%
    set dirpath=!%%namepath%%!
    set dirpath=!%namepath%%%amepath%%!
    set dirpath=!!name!path:%dirpath%=%%dirpath%%!

   ::I want to do things with %dirpath% in this routine:
    if not "!dirpath!"=="" (
        cd !dirpath!
        :: call subroutine to get the number of files in the directory
        call :forhere

        do other stuff with var dirpath ...
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
....
::these don't work:
set dirpath=%%namepath%%
            ^^........^^  Not a valid variable reference

set dirpath=!%%namepath%%!
             ^^........^^ Not a valid variable reference 

set dirpath=!%namepath%%%amepath%%!
             ^........^          This has been parsed at start and has no value

set dirpath=!!name!path:%dirpath%=%%dirpath%%!
            ^^    ^..........................^ two "variables" start and end
```

Delayed expasion over a value obtained with delayed expansion does not have a obvious syntax, because this does not exist. It can not directly be done and other commands need to be used

```
....
set "name=%%G"
set "namepath=%%Gpath"

call set "dirpath=%%!namepath!%%"

echo !dirpath!
....
```

Why or how does it work?

When the line is parsed, the only variable referenced is `namepath` with delayed expansion. The double percent signs are a escaped percent sign. So the line is translated into

```
call set "dirpath=%abcpath%"
```

Now, the call is executed, generating a second parse of the line, obtaining the correct value

This can also be done as

```
for %%a in ("!namepath!") do set "dirpath=!%%~a!"
```

In this case, the value inside `namepath` variable is stored into the `for` replaceable parameter and used to obtain the value to assign to the `dirpath` variable

In both cases, two "parse" (in the logic sense) operations are done.

In the first solution the first parse extracts the value of `namepath` and the second parse (invoked by `call` command execution) uses this value as a variable name.

In the second solution, we first get the value inside `namepath` (first "parse") and then this value is used in a new delayed expansion operation to retrieve the value to assign to `dirpath`

Comment: Yey, I like the visualization in the first code block.+1

Comment: This is an excellent and thorough explanation of why my code didn't work and the additional commands were needed. It helps me better understand delayed expansion. Thank you.